# Benefits of MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to build a web application for users to login and do various things on my website such as depositing money, withdrawal money, creating things that require money etc.  I've heard MVC3 Linq and Entity Framework is a good way to build a asp.net c# web application, but I am confused because there are so many ways to build a web application, I guess Im just wondering what is the most standard way to build a website, and what are the benefits of mvc3?

Comment: I don't see why subjective questions like this always have to be closed.  What's the harm?  Why can't think guy ask the community for their opinion on MVC3?!?!?!

Comment: @Adam Rackis, there is nothing wrong with the question, it's just that StackOverflow is not the right place to ask this type of questions.

Comment: Well that only begs the question.  Why isn't it the right place?  There are a lot of smart people around here who wouldn't mind sharing their opinions on things like this.  Why not just let it go?  Surely it takes more energy to vote to close than to just hit the browser's back button and move along.

Comment: @Adam Rackis, because that's the [rules of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If you don't like them don't use it. And by the way I voted to close as not a real question and not as subjective and argumentative.

Comment: Recoding your whole application in a new framework each time Microsoft decides it's a good idea (which is pretty often) is one huge benefit of the MVC3 framework (or, actually, most frameworks Microsoft makes). If only it were a benefit for anybody else other than Microsoft...

Comment: @Eduardo, MVC is a framework the .NET community had been asking for for quite a long time.  It's hardly something MS is forcing anyone to use

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET MVC is a great alternative to ASP.NET WebForms.  I think MVC is far superior because it is "true" web development, dealing with the web as it was intended.  WebForms abstracts much of what's actually going on, leaving you with a very large and complicated framework.

When doing WebForms, you have to work around the Framework and deal with the nuances of the WebControl life cycle, which can be a nightmare.  Things get much easier with MVC because there's no big framework to get in your way.

There's other great frameworks out there too if you want to venture away from the more costly MS solutions.  Django for Python and Ruby on Rails if you know Ruby.  Both are very good and only a small sample of what's out there.

Answer (score 0):

MVC 3 is one of many good frameworks.  I like it specifically because of the Razor View Engine, and community popularity right now.